# Ruby on Rails unpermitted parameters with has many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have order and products, and a join table called orders_products, the order has many products through order_products and accepts nested attributed for it.

When I try to save it keeps saying unpermitted paramters: order_product

**Params**

```
def order_params
    params.require(:order).permit(:id, :order_number, :customer_id, {order_products_attributes: [:id, :order, :product, :quantity ]}, {:product_ids => []})

end
```

**Order model**

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :customer
    has_many :order_products, class_name: "OrderProduct"
    has_many :products, through: :order_products
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :order_products, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

**Order Product model**

```
class OrderProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :product
    belongs_to :order
end
```

**Order controller new action**

```
def new
    @order = Order.new
    @order.order_products.build
end
```

**Order Form**

```
<%= simple_form_for @order do |f| %>
<%= f.input :order_number %>

<%= f.fields_for :order_product do |fa| %>
    <%= fa.input :product, collection: Product.all  %>
    <%= fa.input :quantity %>

    <% end %>

<%= f.association :customer, as: :select %>

<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**Params hash -** {"utf8"=>"√","authenticity_token"=>"yBrH91u0OHTSPnCFO/484Ff6CRtyRLSg5AKD1Lc33k4=", "order"=>{"order_number"=>"0121", "order_product"=>{"product"=>"4", "quantity"=>"5"}, "customer_id"=>"3"}, "commit"=>"Create Order"}

**Unpermitted parameters: order_product**

Answer (score 1):

you are missing `s` here:

```
<%= f.fields_for :order_products do |fa| %>
```

Comment: Ok Ive added this now I get unpermitted parameters: product

Comment: What do your parameters look like now?

Comment: Maybe `product` needs to be an association? `<%= fa.association :product, as: :select, collection: Product.all  %>`.

Comment: Did you find the solution for that @user2829533??